# Changing constructors with jrebel '-noverify' missing

Tags: java, spring, jrebel

I get this while starting my project with `jrebel`

```
'-noverify' missing, changing/adding/removing constructors will not be enabled!
```

i'm using `apache tomcat`, `spring mvc`, `spring-data-jpa` and `querydsl`

so how can i be able to change constructors with jrebel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using eclipse and I add `-Xverify:none` in :
**run as** -> **run configuration** -> **apache tomcat** and in the onglet **arguments** -> **JVM arguments**

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running on Java 1.8u11 or 1.7u65. Try updating to JDK 1.8u25 or 1.7u72.

In 1.8u11 verifier rules were changed and it affected quite a few tools and libraries that excel in bytecode manipulation. Here's the [issue description](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051012).

Comment: thanks i resolved also the problem by adding `-Xverify:none` to the jvm arguments